# spark scala, missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have this function:

```
  def extractTemplateMeraki(IS_serviceCharacteristics: String,keyword:String): String = {
   //some operations here and return a string in the end as a result 
  }
```

I want to pass this function to a udf like that:

```
val getTemplateMerakiUdf= functions.udf(extractTemplateMeraki(_,"HEBERGEMENT"))
```

the second parameter is always fixe in this case, so when I'm reading my dataframe, I use this udf to create a new column with its returned value for each row:

```
val df = mySourceDatframe
  .withColumn("TemplateMeraki",getTemplateMerakiUdf(col("InstalledService_serviceCharacteristics")))

df
  .select("TemplateMeraki")
  .where("TemplateMeraki NOT IN ('')")
  .show()
```

when I start the program, I'm caught by the exception bellow:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => extractTemplateMeraki(x$1, "HEBERGEMENT"))
    val getTemplateMerakiUdf= functions.udf(extractTemplateMeraki(_,"HEBERGEMENT"))
```

I'm new to scala, and I want to know how to pass the second argument without impacting the process of the UDF while handling the dataframe.

Comment: The same code works fine in Spark 3.2.0, but I think using `functions.udf[String, String](...)` would fix this in your case.

Comment: Just curious, what about using scala's default parm syntax? https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html